# How do I get the values of the cell with the help of data-cell-index using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="game--con" class="game--container" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(1, auto);">

     <div data-cell-index="0" class="cell">A</div>

    <div data-cell-index="1" class="cell">B</div>

</div></div>
```

I am trying to get the values A and B using data-cell-index in javascript.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query selectors to the rescue! You can use elem[attr="value"] to get an element by an attribute.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(`div[data-cell-index]`).forEach(element => {
  console.log(element.innerText);
})
```

```html
<div id="game--con" class="game--container" style="grid-template-columns: repeat(1, auto);">
  <div data-cell-index="0" class="cell">A</div>
  <div data-cell-index="1" class="cell">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get only the values A and B

Comment: `document.querySelector(\`div[data-cell-index="0"]\`).innerText`